# webpack serve giving "Invalid regular expression" error

Tags: webpack

I am trying to run `webpack serve`.

It's giving `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+|\p{Lowercase_Letter}|\d)(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+)/: Invalid escape`

In this line https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/c90dfadbc6c5ac1ab4bda2cc106958b65fb5e6e7/lib/cli.js#L67

```
"webpack": "5.1.3",
"webpack-cli": "4.0.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"

Node 12.19.0
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm having the same issue just today. I solve it with updating my node version to the latest stable version

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Done. Node 12.19.0. Still issue persist. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me too, thank you ! for some people, in order to use the version just installed, it might be necessary to explicitly specify the node version to use : `nvm use stable`

Answer (score 4):

I was running Node 8.9.1 instead of the latest stable version, which was causing the problems.

```
nvm install stable
nvm use stable
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Node 12, Webpack 5.3.1), updating webpack-cli to 4.2.0 solved this error

Answer (score 1):

I could not upgrade to the latest **node** because it would have forced me to upgrade my Angular sites. I used this command to fix the error:

```
npm install webpack@4.42.0 webpack-cli@3.3.11 webpack-dev-server@3.10.3 --save-dev
```

Basically it forces a version of **webpack** that does not have the error.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu I first removed node.js and reinstalled using snap, which solved it for me

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo snap remove node
sudo snap install node --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, I swith the node version from 8.x to 16.x and fix it using this command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% nvm list
->      v8.17.0
       v10.24.1
       v16.13.0
        v17.2.0
         system
default -> 8 (-> v8.17.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v17.2.0) (default)
stable -> 17.2 (-> v17.2.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1
lts/erbium -> v12.22.7 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.18.2 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.13.1 (-> N/A)
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/crx-selection-translate% nvm use 16
Now using node v16.13.0 (npm v8.1.0)
```

hope it help with others. The webpakc version `"webpack": "^5.67.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone who comes along this issue:
`Invalid regular expression: /(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+|\p{Lowercase_Letter}|\d)(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+)/:` is very likely related to a NodeJS which was build with `--with-intl=none` and does not include [RegExp Unicode Property Escapes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes)